# Custom Mouse Pointer in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mouse

I have created a game with custom mouse cursor. the problem is, its not always on top of all moiveclips. I am keep adding new movieclips on every stage. I searched through the net  but not got the proper solution yet. Can anyone help me out ?
Thanx in advance

Comment: Instead of hiding the mouse and using a movieclip that follows where the mouse is, you should probably use a [custom native cursor](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/native-mouse-cursors.html).    [Here is an additional example](http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmedia/2010/12/working-with-native-custom-cursors-in-flash/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ADDED,addedToStageHandler);

function addedToStageHandler(e:Event):void{
myMouseCursor.parent.setChildIndex(myMouseCursor, myMouseCursor.parent.numChildren-1);
}
```

it will catch event when something added to the stage and automatically place your mouse object at the highest level

Comment: thanx for the quick reply.. one small question though, should i write this in document root class or in custom pointer's class ?

Comment: @AbhishekWankhede in document root , why not. and put the real instance name instead of `myMouseCursor`

Comment: @Cherniv- thanx a lot, it worked like a charm.. still a doubt for u to clear it up, can't by any mean i put this in the custom mouse pointers class ?

Comment: @AbhishekWankhede now when it works , of course it will be good practice to move it to more relevant place. try to put it in your class but remember that you can access the `stage` only after your `movieclip` is added to `display list` (or at `stage` itself)